# how to get TotalSafePointTime in java11

Tags: java, time, garbage-collection

In java8 it was possible to get TotalSafePointTime - total time when all threads were stopped due to gc and some other reasons.

sun.management.HotspotRuntimeMBean runtime =
        sun.management.ManagementFactoryHelper.getHotspotRuntimeMBean();

runtime.getTotalSafepointTime()

Unfortunatelly package sun.management is internal in java11. What is recommended way how get this information in java11 ? I need to adjust time for calculation in case significant part of consumed time was not spend by calculation.

Comment: Code above is working just fine on Adopt OpenJDK 11 for me

Comment: Are you sure ?  I use adoptopenjdk11.0.7-10 and content of sun.management package cannot be used during compilation althought I agree that I exists since source code is available in IDE. I heard about some switches that enable the package during compilation and usage via introspection but that is probably not right solution that should be used in a future.

Comment: I've made a minimal example https://github.com/aragozin/hotspot_mbean
It builds and passes test of Adopt OpenJDK 11.0.7-10 and 14.0.1-7 with no extra magic. May you just being outsmarted by IDE?

Comment: Thanks, I found that I was outsmarted by JIdea IDE. After little playing also your project was affected. With just your maven project, changing of source and target to 11 result in compilation error. On other side it is interesting that the code compiled with 1.8 can be without problem executed in jvm 11 and 14.